# Garbage Value on Truffle console while executing the commands from a tutorial

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration, truffle-console

I am following the tutorial at:

[JustDev tutorial on medium](https://medium.com/@JusDev1988/reentrancy-attack-on-a-smart-contract-677eae1300f2)

When I execute the command:

```
truffle(ganache)> Victim.deployed().then(contract => victim = contract)
```

I am getting a huge output which is something like that:

> TruffleContract {   constructor:     { [Function: TruffleContract]
>
> ```
>   _constructorMethods: 
>
>    { configureNetwork: [Function: configureNetwork],
>
>      setProvider: [Function: setProvider],
>
>      new: [Function: new],
>
>      at: [AsyncFunction: at],
>
>      deployed: [AsyncFunction: deployed],
>
>      defaults: [Function: defaults],
>
>      hasNetwork: [Function: hasNetwork],
>
>      isDeployed: [Function: isDeployed],
>
>      detectNetwork: [AsyncFunction: detectNetwork],
>
>      setNetwork: [Function: setNetwork],
>
>      setNetworkType: [Function: setNetworkType],
>
>      setWallet: [Function: setWallet],
>
>      resetAddress: [Function: resetAddress],
>
>      link: [Function: link],
>
>      clone: [Function: clone],
>     
>       still goes down to several pages which I am not showing due  to shortage of space
> ```

Somebody please guide me what is the problem.

Zulfi.

Comment: I don't see any problem. It is just truffle trying to be helpful by printing something in the console. It seems to be a contract object.

Comment: Please guide me how to suppress the message?

Comment: I don't think you can suppress those messages. The messages are innocuous and shouldn't cause any problem.